# Создание графика с помощью seaborn

Tags: python, график, seaborn

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На основе этого графика необходимо построить новый, который будет отображать топ-5 платформ[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Результат должен получиться таким
Есть сводная таблица по платформам:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
pt_games = pd.pivot_table(df_games, index='platform', values='name', aggfunc='count')
pt_games.columns = ['games_per_platform']
pt_games.sort_values(by = 'games_per_platform', ascending = False).head(5)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 6))
sns.countplot(data = df_games, x = 'games_per_platform')
```

При создании выдает ошибку. Что нужно использовать - сводную таблицу pt_games или df_games? Что должно быть передано в x?

Comment: судя по скрину, у вас platform - это название индекса датафрейма, поэтому попробуйте передать в x  df_games.index, либо вообще не указывать x

Comment: И исправьте вопрос - код и стек ошибок в вопросе должны быть в текстовом виде. у вас  должно остаться только два скриншота - ваш результат и желаемый.